# Maximal Abelian von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that are square integrable w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

What is a concrete maximal von Neumann algebra of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of masas in $B(H)$. They can be classified in two kinds, discrete and continuous (and and direct sums thereof).

The canonical example of a continuous masa in your setting would be $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, seeing as multiplication operators.

The canonical example of a discrete masa is the *diagonal masa*: you fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, and consider the corresponding orthogonal projections $\{E_n\}$. Then
$$
A=\{\sum_ka_kE_k:\ a\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\}
$$
would be the diagonal masa corresponding to the orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Not that you gain anything, but if you want to  make this concrete, you can take $\{e_n\}$ to be the [Hermite Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158196/22857). Or you can use a double index and define
$$
e_{n,m}=e^{2\pi in(x-m)}\,1_{[m,m+1)},\qquad n,m\in\mathbb Z.
$$
This would make
$$
(E_{n,m}f)(x)=\langle f,e_{n,m}\rangle\,e_{n,m}=\bigg(\int_m^{m+1}f(t)\,e^{-2\pi i (t-n)}\,dt\bigg)\,e^{2\pi in(x-m)}\,1_{[m,m+1)}.
$$
In this case $A$ would consist of the operators
$$
(T_af)(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_{n,m}\,\bigg(\int_m^{m+1}f(t)\,e^{-2\pi i (t-n)}\,dt\bigg)\,e^{2\pi in(x-m)},\qquad x\in[m,m+1),
$$
where $a\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z^2)$.

Comment: Regarding $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, can it be seen as the von Neumann algebra generated by $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e., its double commutant)?

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Very good! I suspect that it can be "proved" by checking that elements in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ commute with elements in $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$, and noting that $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a von Neumann algebra, right?

Comment: No, you need **double** commutant. Easiest way is probably to show that $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is wot-dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Of course you are right!! I also wrote double commutant.... :) anyway, I gues your suggestion is easier. Thanks again.

Comment: What are the precise definition of continuous masas and concrete masas?  Does there exist releationships between non-atomic masas and continuous masas?

Comment: Non-atomic=continuos. Atomic=discrete.