# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x) p_n (x) e^{-x^2}dx =0$?

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

I'm confused about
[Orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by Hermite Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158196/orthonormal-basis-for-l2-mathbbr-by-hermite-polynomials) of the answer.
( The satement $
A_{n,m(n)} \rightarrow -\int f(x)^2 e^{-x^2} dx$ )

The following hold?

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^nf(x) e^{-x^2}dx=0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, and

$(p_n(x))$ be polynomial sequence. Then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x) p_n (x) e^{-x^2}dx =0$$

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be harder than I think, but this looks like we're just going to use linearity of the integral and then make the estimate $\| \int_{-n}^n -  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins Thank you for your comment. The difficult part is to use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^nf(x) e^{-x^2}dx=0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$

Comment: An important bit of advice here is not to overstate the claims made in the proof you are asking about. They never claim anything equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x) p_n (x) e^{-x^2}dx =0$. Instead they use separate indices $n, m$ for the degree of the polynomial and the limits of integration, and when they do make $m$ a function of $n$, it is a carefully chosen function, not a baldface assumption that $m =n$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I think they are essentially the same thing, so I wrote in a brief way.

Comment: And I am telling you that you are very much mistaken about that. Your "brief" way is not at all equivalent, turning something that is straightforward to prove into something that I strongly suspect is false.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair What I wrote is simpler and easier.

Comment: Simpler, yes. Easier? How so? You cannot figure it out! If you would give proper consideration to the actual statements, you would realize *they work*, while your "easier" version doesn't.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I can't understand why you say that. Please tell me how to use it.

Comment: In the other thread, $n$ is the index of the functions $g_n$ which have compact support but converge to the integrand. Effectively, $n$ controls the limits of integration. $m$ is the index for the polynomial approximations of the $g_n$. Effectively, $m$ controls the degree of the polynomials. By having them separate, they have the freedom to pick for each $n$, whatever value of $m$ was sufficient. But your version demands that degree and width must march in lock-step together. That lack of freedom is what makes your version much harder, not easier.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair My version is easier because it is a special case;  $ supp(g_n)  \sim \{ x | -n < x < n \}$.

Comment: No, that is part of why it is simpler. And if that had been all you did, I would agree that it is at least not harder. However the other simplification you made (and conveniently ignored in that comment) makes the matter much harder.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I answered all.
what's left?

Comment: Your answer is only relevant to the first two sentences of my comment. You completely ignored the rest.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair No. I answered about it.

Comment: With that manifestly false claim, I fail to see any point in continuing this conversation.

Comment: I never said $m=n$.