# Show Fourier transform of $f(x,y) = (x^4 - 6x^2 y^2 + y^4) e^{-\pi (x^2 + y^2) t} $ is itself

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

After the null-result in my previous question I would like someone to demonstrate this function is it's own Fourier transform:

If we set $f(x,y) = (x^4 - 6x^2 y^2 + y^4) e^{-\pi (x^2 + y^2) t} $ when we'd like to show that $\mathcal{F}(f) $ is $f$ itself.  The answer in this previous question states (but does not show) that this is always true for harmonic function.  ("Harmonic" here means something like $\nabla^2 u = 0$ since $f = u(x)\, e^{-x^2 }$ basically.)

$$ \widehat{f}(m,n) = \int_0^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy \; \left[ e^{2\pi i \,(\,mx + ny\,)} \big(x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4\big)\,e^{-\pi\,(x^2 + y^2)\,t} \right] $$

You don't have to do the double-Fourier integral, but can very quickly come up with the answer in some other way. These rules seem the way to go:

- $f(x+h) \longrightarrow \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i h \xi}$
- $f(x) e^{-2\pi i xh} \longrightarrow \hat{f}(\xi+h)$
- $f(\delta x) \longrightarrow \delta^{-1}\hat{f}(\delta^{-1}\xi)$
- $f'(x) \longrightarrow 2\pi i \xi \hat{f}(\xi)$
- $-2\pi i x f(x) \longrightarrow \frac{d}{d\xi}\hat{f}(\xi)$

Hopefully now I have a nonzero result . If you wish show that:

$$ \big[ \nabla^2 u(x,y) = 0 \big] \longrightarrow \Bigg[ \mathcal{F}:  u(x,y) \, e^{-\pi(x^2 + y^2)t} \to   \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,u(a,b) \, e^{-\pi(a^2 + b^2)/t} \Bigg]  $$
The original question:

[Poisson summation example $ f\big(x,y \big) = \big(x^2 - y^2\big)\,e^{-\pi\,(x^2 + y^2)\,t} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479450/poisson-summation-example-f-bigx-y-big-bigx2-y2-big-e-pi-x2)

Comment: The polynomial $\phi(x,y)=x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4$ is harmonic of degree $4$. Then $\overline f=(\pm i)^4f$ where $f(x,y)=\phi(x,y) \exp(-\pi(x^2+y^2))$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that's not obvious to me, could you sketch a proof that result?  I'd put a check mark to that...

Comment: Show that $(\partial_x+i\partial_y)^k e^{-\pi (x^2+y^2)} = (-2\pi)^k (x+iy)^k  e^{-\pi (x^2+y^2)}$

Comment: @reuns is that a [pseudodifferential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator) ?  I guess if $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it's OK.

Comment: Of course $k \in \mathbb{N}$ since we are treating polynomials. Since $\partial_x\partial_y = \partial_y\partial_x$, $(\partial_x+i\partial_y)^k$ is well-defined.

Comment: If $f(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^d c_k (x+iy)^k$ then $(\partial_x+i\partial_y) f(x,y) = 0$. Thus $(\partial_x+i\partial_y) f(x,y) e^{-\pi (x^2+y^2)} = ?$ Finally write your harmonic polynomial as $ \sum_{k=0}^d c_k (x+iy)^k+ \sum_{k=0}^d b_k (x-iy)^k$ use what I said and conclude with the FT of the Gaussian and the derivative property of the FT.

Comment: Can you put the general harmonic polynomial case in an answer now ?

Comment: @reuns I'll answer my own questions.